# Convert CSV file format to Breakline CSV format file

Tags: python, r

I have a csv file with almost 36000 rows.The format of csv file is 
x,y,Polygon number, Z

I would like to arrange this csv file in the below mentioned format. Let’s say in this example, Polygon number 2,3, 4, 5, points are in the 3rd column. I would like to take x,y,z of the each polygon vertices and write 3 before it starts that polygon vertices and END at the end of the polygon vertices. Here you will observe that polygon vertices 2 is with in number "3" and "END" in the output file.

Original CSV file

[image]

**Export Breakline CSV format file**

[image]

Comment: I wonder if this would be more suitable at [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) instead as it seems you only want to add some breaks to the csv =)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using python 2.7, this should get you by.

```
import csv

count = 2
with open("path/to/outcsv.csv", 'w') as fp:
    a = csv.writer(fp)
    a.writerow("3")
with open("path/to/lookup.csv") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for item in reader:
        if str(count) == item['Polygon number']:
            with open("path/to/outcsv.csv", 'a') as fp:
                a = csv.writer(fp)
                a.writerow([item['x'],item['y'],item['z']])
        else:
            count +=1          
            with open("path/to/outcsv.csv", 'a') as fp:
                a = csv.writer(fp)
                a.writerow(["END"])
                a.writerow("3")
                a.writerow([item['x'],item['y'],item['z']])

with open("path/to/outcsv.csv", 'a') as fp:
    a = csv.writer(fp)
    a.writerow(["END"])
```